# Access Pointer to typedef of Byte Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, typedef

Take the following code:

```
typedef UCHAR MY_BUFFER[6];

class MY_CLASS
{
    MY_BUFFER m_buffer;

    void Initialize(const MY_BUFFER* newBuffer)
    {
        memcpy(m_buffer, *newBuffer, sizeof(MY_BUFFER));
    }
};
```

In the above Initialize function, is that the correct way to copy the bytes from newBuffer into m_buffer? Or should the Initialize function be more like this:

```
    void Initialize(const MY_BUFFER* newBuffer)
    {
        memcpy(&m_buffer, newBuffer, sizeof(MY_BUFFER));
    }
```

Comment: Strangely enough, both will work. I would argue that the first expresses the intent clearer.

Comment: What about the syntax Frank Puffer suggested? The reason I ask, is that OACR (build time analysis tool) complains about the first version, but I am unsure exactly what I should be using.

Comment: You could also use `memcpy(&m_buffer[0], &(*newBuffer)[0], sizeof(MY_BUFFER));`

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Yes, but why should you do this?

Comment: @FrankPuffer: Consistency if nothing else but I'd actually go with `void Initialize(const MY_BUFFER & newBuffer) { std::copy(std::begin(newBuffer), std::end(newBuffer), std::begin(m_buffer)); }` anyway. (Instead of that `C` code in disguise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
void Initialize(const MY_BUFFER newBuffer)
{
    memcpy(m_buffer, newBuffer, sizeof(MY_BUFFER));
}
```

Both arguments of `memcpy`have to be addresses.

Comment: I'd expect `m_buffer` to be `UCHAR[6]` ad `newBuffer` to be `UCHAR(*)[6]`.

Comment: Pleae not the typo I have just corrected in my answer: It makes no sense to pass the pointer to the array.

Comment: You're wrong. It makes sense since passing arrays by value is impossible. You could pass by reference but the question is about the call to `memcpy` rather than the interface of `MY_CLASS`.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: I think I know what you mean, it *looks* as if the array is passed by value, while actually just its address is passed and `newBuffer` is actually just a `UCHAR*` inside the function. Considering that, I suggest to declare the argument type as `const UCHAR* newBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

I'd say your first example would be the way to go (eventhough OACR complains) since you neither apply `&` nor `sizeof` and both array expression should decay into pointers. You can enforce that by using:

```
memcpy(&m_buffer[0], &(*newBuffer)[0], sizeof(MY_BUFFER));
```

*As a sidenote: The `c++`-"way" of doing things (when it comes to a static size buffer) would probably be more like:*

```
// template MY_CLASS to be able to change buffer size later
template<std::size_t N>
class MY_CLASS
{
  // use std::array instead of C-style array
  // and add direct brace initialization for zero initialization
  std::array<unsigned char, N> m_buffer{};
public:
  // value (zero) initialization
  MY_CLASS() = default;
  // constructor for copy initialization
  MY_CLASS(std::array<unsigned char, N> const &init_buffer)
    : m_buffer(init_buffer) { }
};
```